# What happens to the soul when dozing for a minute or ten?

Tags: sleep, soul

Tradition tells us the soul leaves the body when sleeping. Is the same true when drowsing in a chair, which is usually not a deep sleep and you are still aware of background noise?

Comment: The Mishnah Brurah ([4:34](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=19)) says that ruach ra (evil spirit) only rests on the hands after sleeping sixty breaths. For how long sixty breaths is, in the Bi'ur Halachah to 4:16 he quotes a few opinions that range from 3 minutes to 3 hours.

Comment: היכי דמי נתנמנם? - אמר רב אשי: נים ולא נים תיר ולא תיר, כגון דקרי ליה ועני, ולא ידע לאהדורי סברא, וכי מדכרו ליה מדכר.

Comment: @Fred can you please translate that?

Comment: @Izzy "What's considered dozing? Rav Ashi said: Asleep but not asleep, awake but not awake. Such that if you call to him he will respond, but can't give a thoughtful response, and if he is reminded (what he heard) when he was dozing, he can recall it." My point is that is is not the same thing as regular sleep.

Comment: @ba, sounds like the makings of an answer.

Comment: @msh210 The question asks about the removal of the soul; the comment addresses ruach ra. If they have the same status, it would be a good answer, I think, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: @ba, hence "the makings of". `:-)`